# Azure pipeline use star in trigger paths include

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd

I want to create a pipeline trigger in azure devops that triggers only on changes in folder named src/Subscription.*

My Folder structure:

- src

  - Subscription.Data
  - Subscriptin.Api
  - Subscription.Shared

How my pipeline looks

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - development
      - master
      - release
paths:
  include:
    - src/Subscription.**/*
```

How can i change the include to trigger on file changes in all the folders ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i change the include to trigger on file changes in all the folders ?

Until September 8, 2021, this is still a known request on our main product forum：

[Support wildcards (*) in Trigger > Path Filters](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-wildcards-in-trigger-path-filters-1/366363)

Now, it is possible now as it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters), **but** the function needs to be improved:

> Wild cards can be used when specifying inclusion and exclusion branches for CI or PR triggers in a pipeline YAML file. However, they cannot be used when specifying path filters. For instance, you cannot include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*. This has been pointed out as an inconvenience by several customers. This update fills this gap. Now, you can use wild card characters (**, *, or ?) when specifying path filters.

Now, we could use `*` but not `**` & `*`.

As workaround for this issue:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - development
      - master
      - release
  paths:
    include:
      - src/Subscriptin.Api/*
      - src/Subscription.Data/*
      - src/Subscription.Shared/*
```